# Multiple browser screenshot with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm completely new to Selenium but I'm aware it's capable of taking browser screenshots. Though, I was wondering if it's able to take screenshots of multiple browsers, specifically chrome, firefox and IE.

Thanks

PS: I'm working with c#

Comment: Run each browser via webdriver with Selenium and take a shot of each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to take screenshots with Selenium for multiple browsers, there are some things that you might want to consider before choosing it as your implementation:

1. As emd mentioned, you will need to create a driver for each type of browser that you wish to take screenshots of as each has a different (internal) implementation for taking screenshots,
2. Currently the ChromeDriver is not capable of taking a full-screen screenshot (it will only take a screenshot of the current viewport, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294) for more details),
3. Selenium is unable to take screenshots when a dialog box is present. If you are trying to take a screenshot of an unexpected dialog, this can be quite annoying.

As an alternative, you could implement a generic screenshot method in .Net. Have a look into Graphics.CopyFromScreen() method from System.Drawing. This implementation will be browser independent. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen.aspx) for more details, or Google search some examples of its use for full screen screenshots =]